# Negation of "<=>" hive operator does not work properly?

Tags: hive, operators, hiveql

I have to add some intro here, because SO says that my question is mostly code ;)

Here is my test:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  c1 string,
  c2 string
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (NULL, NULL),
  ('A', NULL),
  ('A', 'B'),
  ('A', 'A')
;

SELECT *, (c1 <=> c2) as is_equal, (NOT (c1 <=> c2)) as is_not_equal
FROM test;
```

and results:

```
test.c1,test.c2,is_equal,is_not_equal
NULL,NULL,true,NULL
A,NULL,false,NULL
A,B,false,true
A,A,true,false
```

I'd rather expect:

```
test.c1,test.c2,is_equal,is_not_equal
NULL,NULL,true,false
A,NULL,false,true
A,B,false,true
A,A,true,false
```

Is this a bug in hive?

**EDIT**

This query works as expected:

```
SELECT *,
(c1 is null and c2 is null) or (c1 is not null and c2 is not null and c1 = c2) as is_equal,
(NOT ((c1 is null and c2 is null) or (c1 is not null and c2 is not null and c1 = c2))) as is_not_equal
FROM test;
```

**EDIT2**

We use Hive 1.2.1 (from HDP 2.6.2)

Comment: i am unable to reproduce this issue and get the expected result. Which version of Hive are you using?

Comment: We use Hive 1.2.1 (from HDP 2.6.2)